# error: attribute android:useAndroidX not found

Tags: android

I was trying to run the app but it failed because "Android resource linking failed":

> error: attribute android:useAndroidX not found.
>   error: failed processing manifest.

But the attribute is indeed in the file so I am not sure why it still does not work.

The attribute to enable AndroidX is available in manifest file, the debug manifest file and also the gradle properties after the project migrated to AndroidX, all the dependencies are updated so I am not sure what to do.

This is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.amethyst.within">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_rate_on"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:useAndroidX="true">
        <activity android:name=".NewNoteActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the manifest debug file (above the file it is stated it is not recommended for editing, but when clicked on the error, it linked to this file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.amethyst.within"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="28" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Although the *SdkVersion is captured in gradle build files, this is required for non gradle builds -->
    <!-- <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" /> -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_rate_on"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:useAndroidX="true" >
        <activity android:name="com.amethyst.within.NewNoteActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.amethyst.within.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:permission="com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.permission.LAUNCH_FEDERATED_SIGN_IN"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.amethyst.within.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.amethyst.within.com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
            android:multiprocess="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the gradle properties file:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

gradle dependency file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.amethyst.within"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.jackandphantom.android:androidlikebutton:1.2.0'
    implementation files('libs/forismatic-api-java.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:useAndroidX="true"` from manifest file. It's not an existing attribute.